# How to pull email address form user table and send email to that address using $_SESSION[user_id] variable?

Tags: php, mysql

How to pull email address form user table and send email to that address using `$_SESSION[user_id]` variable ?

At the end of the payment process I would like to send confirmation email to the user. User id is stored in session and I would like to send confirmation to the email adress stored in user table.

```
<?php
$to = "recipient@example.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
?>
```

how to using query insert appropriate email associated with $_SESSION[user_id] variable?

```
$q = "SELECT email from users where id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$to = "email";
$subject = "Confirmation";
$body = "Hi,\n\nConfirmation?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

I have info email successfully sent but email never arrives...
during the registration process I sent email using :

```
$body = "Thank you for registering at <...>. Welcome to digital world of knowledge.";
mail ($_POST['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: admin@ttt.com');
```

Comment: It all depends on the way your db is set up. Possibly using a `SELECT`-statement. What db are you using?

Comment: And what do your tables look like? A db structure would come in handy.

Comment: After your edit: fetch the data from `$r` using `$row = $r->fetch_assoc();` and replace the `$to = "email";` line by `$to = $row['email'];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a select query based on the user id to get email something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT email from user where user_id='".$_SESSION[user_id]."'";
```

then use that email to perform mail functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the email address from the user object:

```
$user  = User::getByID($_SESSION[user_id]);
$email = $user->getEmail();
```

This code is just exemplary, it depends how your user-object works. If you don't have one, then my answer is a suggestion that you create yourself a user object.

Answer (score 0):

With out getting an `email address` from the `Database` , its not possible to do that,

or else

After the user login success, you can set one more session varaible

```
$_SESSION['email'] = 'abc@example.com'
```

Comment: If the email is needed more often in the application the suggestion to store it into the session is a good one.

Comment: Yes, Otherwise introduce a new function with query is different way to achieve this

Comment: Yes, function is a good idea and even better than a function is a small object with some useful methods, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15926343/2261774